# How this R syntax works?

Tags: r, string, syntax, frame, levels

For example, if we have a data frame called x in R with a column which have some levels and we want to obtain that levels as strings, this should work:

```
levels(x$column)[x$column]
```

Anyone can explain me how this R syntax works?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple one column data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "c"))
```

The `levels()` function all the character levels for the input.  Then, we subset that character vector using the level indices themselves:

```
levels(df$x)[df$x]
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: I do not get that answer. Why doesn't  `levels(df$x)[c("a", "b", "c")]` do the same?  `df$x`does not yield indices like you say but a vector of characters.

Comment: @PascalIv Because in your version you're passing in a character vector, not a factor.  Try `levels(df$x)[as.factor(c("a", "b", "c"))]` and it should work.

Comment: Forgot about that stringsAsFactor stuff. Thanks!

Comment: I get what are you trying to explain, but I was expecting an answer explaining that kind of indexing, since in my opinion it isn't intuitive comparing it to another programming languages. You can index a vector longer than levels(df$x), e.g.: levels(df$x)[as.factor(c("a", "b", "c", "c"))])                                  
It sounds pretty weird to me, maybe I'm not used to R a lot so that's the reason... But thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: @HéctorOlivera Yes, but in that case the fourth element would return `NA`, because that level does not exist in the factor `df$x`.

Comment: I've corrected it, I was thinking on "c" in the last element as you can see. But yes, I get it :)